# Simple standalone Windows 2019 Server - DNS Manager shows 2 DNS servers, is this normal?

Tags: windows-server-2019, dns-server

recently set up a Windows 2019 Essentials machine, standalone server, simple local area network with a handful of Win10 workstations

The server is the Domain Controller and runs Active Directory

Now, when I go into DNS Manager, it shows 2 DNS servers - is this normal? I simply ran through the wizard when adding a DNS server. Didn't realise I created two. Wondering if this could be a problem, moving forwards? Or is this normal? Perhaps it added a second when I ran through the active directory wizard?

First one is called
COMPUTERNAME

the other is called
COMPUTERNAME.ad.mycompany.com

Comment: is computername and computername the same?

Comment: yes, both identical computername

Answer (score 2):

It's the same server listed by it's NetBIOS name and by it's FQDN. You can remove either one from the console, or you can leave them as is.

Comment: Yes, it appears one is netbios and the other FQN like you say. I take it only one DNS server exists in a typical installation, not two like ours? I can remove the netbios one without any repercussion? Could leaving the two alone cause a clash in anyway?